# Handle validation for non numeric characters getting passed to Integer variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, annotations, numberformatexception

Is there an annotation that could be used to prevent the following error from getting thrown by my Java application if I send a non numerical value for year in my GET request?

I currently have this:

```
@NotNull
@Digits(integer = 4, fraction = 0, message = "Provide valid Year in the format YYYY")
@Min(value = 1900, message = "Year must be greater than 1900")
private Integer year;
```

When I pass a value with letters I get a `NumberFormatException` before `@Digits` and `@Min` is executed. I also tried @Pattern with a regex value but that caused a 500 error.

```
"Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer' for property 'yearOfReg'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"20c15\"
```

Comment: you should correct your values: "20c15\ is not a valid numerical value

Comment: That's just an example to show the issue I'm facing. Basically, if a user sends an invalid value like the one above, I don't want them getting that message in the response. I'd like to replace it with something of my own.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very short: no. That's because the validation is configured for the `Integer year` field. That means that the field must get populated before it can be validated. That population fails if you submit a value that cannot be parsed to an `Integer`.

The best way to handle this case is to add error handling for the mapping exception. For Jackson that's a `MismatchedInputException`.

An alternative is to change the field to a `String`. That allows you to use `@Pattern`, but you will need to convert yourself. That can be done in the class itself using a getter.